# Prevent duplicate routes in express.js

Tags: express

Is there a nice way to prevent duplicate routes from being registered in express? I have a pretty large application with hundreds of routes across different files, and it gets difficult to know if I've already registered a certain route when I go to add a new one. For example, I'd like to throw an error when express gets to routes487.js:

File: routes1.js

```
var ctrl = require('../controllers/testctrl');
var auth = require('../libs/authentication');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/hi', auth.getToken, ctrl.hi);
    app.get('/there', auth.getToken, ctrl.there);
};
```

File: routes487.js

```
var ctrl = require('../controllers/testctrl487');
var auth = require('../libs/authentication');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/hi', auth.getToken, ctrl.hi487);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a custom solution by wrapping express methods with the validation. Consider the following modification to your express app:

```
// route-validation.js
module.exports = function (app) {
  var existingRoutes = {}
    , originalMethods = [];

  // Returns true if the route is already registered.
  function routeExists(verb, path) {
    return existingRoutes[verb] &&
      existingRoutes[verb].indexOf(path) > -1;
  }

  function registerRoute(verb, path) {
    if (!existingRoutes[verb]) existingRoutes[verb] = [];
    existingRoutes[verb].push(path);
  }

  // Return a new app method that will check repeated routes.
  function validatedMethod(verb) {
    return function() {
      // If the route exists, app.VERB will throw.
      if (routeExists(verb, arguments[0]) {
        throw new Error("Can't register duplicate handler for path", arguments[0]);
      }
      // Otherwise, the route is saved and the original express method is called.
      registerRoute(verb, arguments[0]);
      originalMethods[verb].apply(app, arguments);
    }
  }

  ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'all'].forEach(function (verb) {
    // Save original methods for internal use.
    originalMethods[verb] = app[verb];
    // Replace by our own route-validator methods.
    app[verb] = validatedMethod(verb);
  });
};
```

You just need to pass your app to this function after creation and duplicate route checking will be implemented. Note that you might need other "verbs" (`OPTIONS`, `HEAD`).

If you don't want to mess with express' methods (we don't know whether or how express itself or middleware modules will use them), you can use an intermediate layer (i.e., you actually wrap your app object instead of modifying its methods). I actually feel that would be a better solution, but I feel lazy to type it right now :)